# WHERE clause suppresses duplicate rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm having problems with a table copy erroring due to a primary key constraint when the primary key is on the new table. In doing some investigation by not setting a primary key I was able to find a duplicate row in my source table, still unsure how it got in there but what I'm more curious about is the rest of what I found.

Here goes:

I have a SQL query that selects the full table and returns the following:

```
SELECT *
 FROM search_term_suggest
 order by search_term
```

you can see the value is duplicated and I had to scroll through the table to find it.

[image: SQL Results]

But when I limit my query to:

```
SELECT *
 FROM search_term_suggest
 where search_term = 'b'
```

you can see it filters out the first value. There are no triggers on the database or anything I can see that would limit the select query.

[image: SQL Results with "where" clause added]

I'm running SQL 2008 r2. Any help is greatly appreciated.  The database I'm copying the table to is a SQL 2000 database and when selecting using the same queries as above I get the results I would expect.

**EDIT:** search_term is a varchar(100), search_term_suggest is a table not a view.

Comment: Is `search_term_suggest` a table or a view? What is the datatype of `search_term`? (Triggers wouldn't be relevant because there is no such thing as a SELECT trigger.)

Comment: Can you tell us what the results look like when running: `SELECT *
 FROM search_term_suggest WHERE search_term LIKE 'b%'`?

Comment: @GerardoLima adding the LIke clause does return both records.  see comments in Aaron's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess: `search_term` is a `CHAR/NCHAR` and has trailing spaces (or trailing spaces are being considered for other reasons). Try:

```
WHERE RTRIM(search_term) = 'b';
```

You may also need to eliminate tabs/carriage returns, which aren't affected by trim operations.

```
WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(search_term,
  CHAR(9), ''), CHAR(10), ''), CHAR(13), ''))) = 'b';
```

Note that both of the above queries preclude using an index, so if there is an index on `search_term` you should probably rebuild it after changing the column to `varchar` or `nvarchar` and making sure that padding settings and whitespace aren't causing the problem.

Other guesses: as @Dems points out, check the length of both columns on the first query. Also try changing your where clause to the following, for investigation purposes only:

```
WHERE search_term LIKE 'b%'
  AND LEN(search_term) > 1;
```

If you get any result there, then you can say:

```
DECLARE @val VARCHAR(100), @i INT;

DECLARE c CURSOR LOCAL STATIC READ_ONLY FAST_FORWARD 
  FOR SELECT search_term FROM dbo.search_term_suggest
  WHERE search_term LIKE 'b%'
    AND LEN(search_term) > 1;

OPEN c;

FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @val;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
  SET @i = 1;
  PRINT '-----' + @val + ' (' + RTRIM(LEN(@val)) + ')';
  WHILE @i <= LEN(@val)
  BEGIN
    PRINT SUBSTRING(@val, @i, 1) + ' = ' + ASCII(SUBSTRING(@val, @i, 1));
    SET @i = @i + 1;
  END

  FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @val;
END
CLOSE c;
DEALLOCATE c;
```

This will help you troubleshoot what is in that column aside from the `b` - it may be whitespace you haven't checked for (e.g. a tab or carriage return) or other non-printing characters.

Comment: It's a varchar(100) - Sorry forgot to mention that above - and adding the RTRIM gives the same results.

Comment: @Robert - If you add `LEN(search_term) AS length,` to the first query, what are the results?

Comment: one row is a length of 5 and the one that is returning is a length of 1. so that explains why it's showing only 1 but why wouldn't the RTRIM show the second one? So now my question is why would that cause a primary key constraint?

Comment: (1) RTRIM does not trim tabs/carriage returns/line feeds. (2) for a primary key constraint violation to occur, the values must be considered equivalent. Since we don't know yet what those other 4 characters are, we can't tell you why.

Comment: Ok cool. I think I have what I need to move forward.  thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

Could it be that in the 29645 row the search_term value is not 'b', but 'b       ' (i.e. b followed by whitespace)

Answer (score 0):

It must not be a b, just something that looks like a b on the screen, especially if there's a constraint on that column.  If you copy the query results to text, can you search for "b" in a text editor and find it?